# Prevent programs (wine/steam) from disabling monitors

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors, wine, display, steam

I use Kubuntu 18.04 on my Laptop with two monitors connected.

Some programs (Mostly Wine, Steam and Proton) sometimes disable both of my secondary monitors.
For instance, sometimes (not always, which is weird) when I launch Steam all of my monitors would flicker for a while (even the primary monitor) and the secondary monitors would stay black or just one of them stays dark.
This also happens when I launch games in steam (proton / wine) and also when I just type winecfg in my terminal.

How can I permanently prevent applications from turning off my screens?

Sometimes the monitors show up as "disabled" in system settings and sometimes they don't show up at all and I have to pull the HDMI/DP cable and reconnect it.